# How to create a multidimensional array from a .txt-file?

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

Using the `ReadAllLines` dose not create manipulable arrays but only "it is only read text". The code is as follows:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("read.txt");
        foreach (string s in lines)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("press any key to close console.");

        if (2 == 2)
        {
            lines[1][2] = 2;
        }
    }
}
```

The errors reads:

> property or index 'string.this[int]' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

Is there a piece of code that recognizes the numbers and order in the `.txt-file`? The text file is displayed in the following picture:

[image: .txt-file]

Each row in the .txt-file should be a string. I tried using a combination of `foreach` and `for-loop` operators but I was short on what I should write.

```
foreach (string s in lines)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++)
            {
                M[i] = 
            }
        }
```

In the above `M` is a multidimensional array in the same properties as the `.txt-file`.

Comment: Strings are immutable in .NET, you can't modify them once they are created.

Comment: You could just `String.Split` the line by space, that would give you an array of strings, where each would be a number as string. You can then apply `int.Parse` to each "cell" and result would be int[][].

Comment: Does `M[i] = s[i]` not work?

Comment: `File.ReadAllLines("read.txt").Select(x => x.Split('\x20').Select(int.Parse).ToArray()).ToArray()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no built in method for it in .NET. What you can do though, is create a multidimensional array from the file lines like so:

```
private static string[][] ReadAllLines(string filename)
{
    string[] allFileLines = File.ReadAllLines(filename);

    string[][] arr = new string[allFileLines.Length][];

    for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < allFileLines.Length; rowIndex++)
    {
        // Split by the space character and remove blank entries
        arr[rowIndex] = allFileLines[rowIndex].Split(new [] { ' ' },StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    }

    return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a multidimensional char array from text file

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        char[][] arr = new char[numberofline][];

        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("read.txt");

        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < lines[i].Length; j++)
            {
                arr[i][j] = lines[i][j];
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("press any key to close console.");
    }
}
```